# parse error: Invalid numeric literal at EOF at line 1, column 10897

Tags: linux, bash, jq

I want to process data with following format by jq:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "valueX": 11111,
      "valueY": 11111,
    },
    {
      "valueX": 2222,
      "valueY": 2222,
    }
    ...,
    {
      "valueX": 2222,
      "valueY": 2222,
    }
    ],
  "meaningless_data": "x"
}
```

I want to go through data in "`data`" section, which has 100 sets of data. I wrote following, I saved all content into `${input}`, and wanted to print out `valueX`s. I'm able to get echo part printed out but still see a lot of `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at EOF`. How could I get it fixed?

```
for row in $(echo "${input}" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do
    _jq() {
     echo ${row} | base64 --decode | jq -r ${1}
    }

    for i in {0..100}; do
        echo "Printing valueX: "$(_jq '.['"${i}"'].valueX')" . "
    done

done
```

Comment: Remove three trailing `,` from your JSON file. Find syntax errors: `jq '' file`

Comment: Hey Cyrus, I don't quite get. Are you talking about `,` after `}`? How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the pseudo-JSON, you could use a tool such as https://hjson.org/. See the jq FAQ for further details and other options: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ